# GUI - calculating age from birthdate

Tags: java, swing, date, jbutton, actionlistener

I just learned a little bit about GUIs and I'm stuck on a really dumb part of my homework. Basically, the homework is asking for the user to enter their birthday and the GUI will output their age. I have everything working, I just can't figure out how to make the user birthday text field have the "/" in a birthday (like, 1/2/1976) and then have it calculate that. I can do it with just the year, but not with the whole birthday. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class UserBirthday extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JLabel userBirthdayLabel; 
    private JLabel userAgeLabel; 
    private JTextField userAgeDisplay; 
    private JTextField userBirthdayDisplay; 
    private JButton calcButton;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;

    UserBirthday(){

        GridBagConstraints layoutConst = null;
        setTitle("Birthday");

        userBirthdayLabel = new JLabel ("Enter birth date: ");
        userAgeLabel = new JLabel ("Your age is");

        userBirthdayDisplay = new JTextField(15);
        userBirthdayDisplay.setEditable(true);
        userBirthdayDisplay.setText("0"); //I'm thinking this is the problem area?
        userBirthdayDisplay.addActionListener(this);

        userAgeDisplay = new JTextField(15);
        userAgeDisplay.setEditable(false);

        JButton calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        calcButton.addActionListener(this);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(calcButton);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();

        layoutConst.gridx = 0;
        layoutConst.gridy = 0;

        layoutConst.insets = new Insets (10, 10, 10, 10);

        add(userBirthdayLabel, layoutConst);

        layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
        layoutConst.gridx = 1;
        layoutConst.gridy = 0;
        layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        add(userBirthdayDisplay, layoutConst);

        layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
        layoutConst.gridx = 0;
        layoutConst.gridy = 1;
        layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        add(userAgeLabel, layoutConst);

        layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
        layoutConst.gridx = 1;
        layoutConst.gridy = 1;
        layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        add(userAgeDisplay, layoutConst);

        layoutConst.gridx = 0;
        layoutConst.gridy = 2;
        layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        add(buttonPanel, layoutConst);  
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String userInput;
        int birthday;

        userInput = userBirthdayDisplay.getText();
        birthday = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

        userAgeDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(2020 - birthday)); //will need to figure out the calculation

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserBirthday topFrame = new UserBirthday();

        topFrame.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        topFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        topFrame.pack();
        topFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Integer.parseInt expects the entire string to represent a single numeric value.  `"1/2/1976"` isn’t text representing a numeric value, it’s text that forms a date (using three numeric values).  You will want to read about [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), then follow PM 77-1’s link to learn how to use that SimpleDateFormat with a JFormattedTextField.

Comment: @VGR thanks for the reply! We haven't learned about SimpleDateFormat yet in my online class so I'm not quite sure how to use it. Looks like I need to import that library and re-write the code using SimpleDateFormat instead of .setText?